# Error installing R package fGarch

Tags: ipython, rpy2

I am trying to install R package fGarch for sometime but there seems to be an issue. I use the following command:

```
import rpy2.interactive as r
import rpy2.interactive.packages 
rlib = r.packages.packages
r.packages.importr("utils")
package_name = "fGarch"
rlib.utils.install_packages(package_name)
```

The installation mostly goes fine except for the warning at the end:

```
/home/vdesai/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py:216:   UserWarning: Conflict when converting R symbol in the package "tools" to a Python symbol (package.dependencies -> package_dependencies while there is already package_dependencies)
warn(msg)
```

When I try to load the package with:

```
%R library(fGarch)
```

I get following error:

```
Error in library(fGarch) : there is no package called ‘fGarch’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), contriburl = contrib.url(repos,     :
installation of package ‘MASS’ had non-zero exit status
2: In (function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), contriburl = contrib.url(repos,  :
installation of package ‘fBasics’ had non-zero exit status
3: In (function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), contriburl = contrib.url(repos,  :
installation of package ‘fGarch’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(fGarch) : there is no package called ‘fGarch’
```

Note that using this package from Rstudio causes no difficulties. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to the following problem. The main idea is to 1) install anaconda, which provides a nice python distribution 2) install R through conda by running a command like: "conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/r r" 3) install rpy2 by running "conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/r rpy2".

Now if you try to install fGarch from ipython notebook, I used to get an error in installing dependencies MASS. But these dependencies are available as package in the conda channel r and we can install them using commands:
conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/r r-mass
conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/r r-fbasics
Then, you should be able to install fGarch from ipython notebook.

The nice thing about this approach is if things do not go as planned you can always delete the package directory or the whole anaconda directory. So it is very easy to experiment.